# How do I mirror selected faces over a selected point?

Tags: mirror

Shift-Ctrl-M does not work because it says "0 faces mirrored, 20 failed"

I can't get mirror modifier to mirror only the faces I have selected

Select->Mirror does not work because it doesn't mirror over the selected origin[image]

[image]

Comment: You can duplicate the faces, scale it to -1 on the x axis with the appropriate transform pivot point, then flip the normals.

Comment: How do I scale it?

Comment: With the S button.

Comment: Thank you, I figured the rest out